# Spark Json - Apply Schema with nullable= false

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to apply nullable=false for my Json file. It is always showing default value as nullable=true.
written my own schema.

```
val carsSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("Name", StringType),
    StructField("Miles_per_Gallon", DoubleType,nullable = false),
    StructField("Cylinders", LongType),
    StructField("Displacement", DoubleType),
    StructField("Horsepower", LongType),
    StructField("Weight_in_lbs", LongType),
    StructField("Acceleration", DoubleType),
    StructField("Year", StringType),
    StructField("Origin", StringType)))
```

df.show()

```
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Miles_per_Gallon: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Cylinders: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Displacement: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Horsepower: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Weight_in_lbs: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Acceleration: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Year: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Origin: string (nullable = true)
```

After some research and convert to RDD and then apply to DF using below code.

```
val jsonRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile(carsDataWithErrorjsonfile)
  val carDF = spark.read
            //.format("json")
          //.option("inferSchema", true)
          .schema(carsSchema)
          .option("mode","permisive") //failFast,permisive,dropMalformed,
          .json(jsonRDD)
```

[image]

it is working as expected. But IDE is showing , passed as rdd to json method is deprecated. Have any alternative option to set nullable=false.

sample dataset

```
{"Name":"chevrolet chevelle malibu", "Miles_per_Gallon":18, "Cylinders":8, "Displacement":307, "Horsepower":130, "Weight_in_lbs":3504, "Acceleration":12, "Year":"1970-01-01", "Origin":"USA"}
```

Comment: Does anyone have idea on this

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else. Are you sure your `carDF` has correct and readable data? can you post the input data?

Comment: Yes.. i can use .show method.. it is working as expected.